# What can I use to connect Java to Video4Linux?

Tags: java, linux, openmoko

I need to talk to Video4Linux (to capture output from a webcam) on a debian system running on an armel system (OpenMoko).  JavaMediaFramework won't work in this case as it only have x86 and AMD versions.  The linux kernel is 2.6.24 (with the v4l drivers compiled in separatly) and I cannot upgrade it (as it is not available on my hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I have been following closely a project called [video4linux4java](http://v4l4j.googlecode.com) . I now works with a lot of drivers (therefore a lot of webcams & capture cards), and produces a JPEG-encoded stream of images captured from a video device. Recently, the author has added classes to report information on the video device itself (webcam, TV tuner, ...). It is simple to use and comes with some examples. One of them (used to test v4l4j) displays a video stream in a JFrame. I use v4l4j in my own app to capture frames from my Logitech Quickcam Sphere AF, and control the pan and tilt. Works Great !

Answer (score -2):

Video 4 Linux devices should be accessible through a device file (like /dev/video).
So I think you can open the device you want to access as you would do with a normal file and then read the stream coming from it.
To have more info about the devices, the video format etc... just check [V4L web site](http://linux.bytesex.org/v4l2/)